# Connect two DB's with JNDI from WebLogic on java SpringBoot with JPA

Tags: java, spring, weblogic, jndi

I have this issue. along 3 days.
When I tried to build the app with maven, i have this isues, but my build was successful, then when I deployed on WebLogic and I call any endpoint this response to me a 500 internal server error.

```
2021-10-29 17:23:47.788  INFO 64993 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.32.Final
2021-10-29 17:23:48.021  INFO 64993 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-10-29 17:23:48.269  WARN 64993 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata

java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc/facturador
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:155) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:146) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:205) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:169) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) [hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) [hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) [hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) [hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final] (....)
```

and

```
2021-10-29 17:23:48.479  INFO 64993 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-10-29 17:23:48.501  INFO 64993 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-10-29 17:23:48.507  WARN 64993 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata

java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc/differenceload
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:155) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:146) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:205) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:169) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) [hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) [hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) [hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) [hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) [hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) [hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152) [hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) [hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) [hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) [hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
```

There is my DataSourceConfig

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;


    @Configuration
    public class DataSourceConfig {
         
            @Bean(name = "primaryDataSource",destroyMethod = "")
            @Primary
            @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.primary")
            public DataSource firstDataSource(){
                return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
            }
    
            @Bean(name = "secondaryDataSource",destroyMethod = "")
            @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.secondary")
            public DataSource secondDataSource(){
                return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
            }
            
    
    }
```

Persistence for one DB

```
import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;



@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/application.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.gt.tigo.diferenceLoad.entities.facturador", entityManagerFactoryRef = "localEntityManager", transactionManagerRef = "localTransactionManager")

public class PersistenceLocalConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(localDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.gt.tigo.diferenceLoad.entities.local" });

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        return em;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public DataSource localDataSource() {

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.primary.jndi-name"));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager localTransactionManager() {

        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(localEntityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

Persistence for other DB

```
import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;



@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/application.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.gt.tigo.diferenceLoad.entities.facturador", entityManagerFactoryRef = "FacturadorEntityManager", transactionManagerRef = "facturadorTransactionManager")

public class PersistenceFacturadorConfig {
    
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean FacturadorEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(facturadorDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.gt.tigo.diferenceLoad.entities.facturador" });

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource facturadorDataSource() {

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.secondary.jndi-name"));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager facturadorTransactionManager() {

        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(FacturadorEntityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

Here it's my weblogic JNDI.
[webLogic jndi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NI7Dm.png)

I tried all things.. but can't solve. please I need some help. Thanks!

```
#Base de datos LOCAL 
spring.datasource.primary.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver 
spring.datasource.primary.jndi-name=jdbc/differenceload 
#Base de datos FACTURADOR 
spring.datasource.secondary.jndi-name=jdbc/facturador 
spring.datasource.secondary.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

Comment: The author has said that there were no problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/76845619/4458220

Answer (score 1):

Finally the problem was in my local config of WebLogic. Really I don't know what is wrong, but my partner try in his environment and really works!

Thanks. I close that because I don't remember where is the error into my WebLogic config.

Best Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Quick look and make some changes in your file.

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.primary.jndi-name=java:/comp/env/jdbc/SecurityDS
spring.datasource.primary.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

spring.datasource.secondary.jndi-name=java:/comp/env/jdbc/TmsDS
spring.datasource.secondary.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

**Configuration:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.primary")
    public JndiPropertyHolder primary() {
        return new JndiPropertyHolder();
    }

    @Bean @Primary
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
        JndiDataSourceLookup dataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        DataSource dataSource = dataSourceLookup.getDataSource(primary().getJndiName());
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean@ ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.secondary")
    public JndiPropertyHolder secondary() {
        return new JndiPropertyHolder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
        JndiDataSourceLookup dataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        DataSource dataSource = dataSourceLookup.getDataSource(secondary().getJndiName());
        return dataSource;
    }

    private static class JndiPropertyHolder {
        private String jndiName;

        public String getJndiName() {
            return jndiName;
        }

        public void setJndiName(String jndiName) {
            this.jndiName = jndiName;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! tanks for your answer. You only have this config class ?.
       
My properties :  spring.datasource.primary.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver                   :  AND   : 
  spring.datasource.primary.jndi-name=jdbc/differenceload

Comment: you have to tell your Weblogic to use some sort of DB. Since it's a server your local DB is not going to work with the deployed applications.

Comment: Yes i tell that , but with your config mi error it's different. When i build.
Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial

Answer (score 0):

You need to lookup your datasources from jndi instead of creating them using `DataSourceBuilder`.  You can do it like this...

```
@Configuration
public class WeblogicResourceConfig {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WeblogicResourceConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public JndiTemplate jndiTemplate() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
        return new JndiTemplate(props);
    }

    // destroyMethod MUST be blank or datasource is removed from jndi tree on
    // see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/17153
    @Bean(destroyMethod = "")
    @Primary
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() throws NamingException {
        return (DataSource) jndiTemplate().lookup(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.primary.jndi-name"));
    }


    // destroyMethod MUST be blank or datasource is removed from jndi tree
    // see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/17153
    @Bean(destroyMethod = "")
    public DataSource secondaryDataSource() throws NamingException {
        return (DataSource) jndiTemplate().lookup(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.secondary.jndi"));
    }
}
```

When creating your `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` inject those datasources above instead of creating new DataSource beans.

Comment: Fine! i tried that. Now i don't know what can I put on weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory